# How to transform null to empty string?

Tags: json, jolt

I need to transform my JSON having `null` values to empty String and UNKNOWN String to empty string.

Here is my JSON looks alike.

```
  {
    "dmarId": 11536,
    "salesForceRegion": "Unknown",
    "industryVertical": null,
    "modifiedDate": "2020-03-10T06:00:56"
  },
  {
    "dmarId": 543,
    "salesForceRegion": null,
    "industryVertical": null,
    "modifiedDate": "2020-03-10T06:00:56"
  }
]
```

Output Json:

```
[
  {
    "dmarId": 11536,
    "salesForceRegion": "",
    "industryVertical": "",
    "modifiedDate": "2020-03-10T06:00:56"
  },
  {
    "dmarId": 543,
    "salesForceRegion": "",
    "industryVertical": "",
    "modifiedDate": "2020-03-10T06:00:56"
  }
]
```

I cannot figure out how to create the spec to work with this configuration.

Comment: Hi Rohit, welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "dmarId": "[].dmarId",
        "modifiedDate": "[&1].modifiedDate",
        "salesForceRegion": {
          "Unknown|null": {
            "# ": "[&3].salesForceRegion"
          }
        },
        "industryVertical": {
          "Unknown|null": {
            "# ": "[&3].industryVertical"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "salesForceRegion": "",
        "industryVertical": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```